# Changing element size inside updateDisplayList method

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I have standard `Group` control and I am writing new layout for it. In this layout I am overriding `updateDisplayList` method. After some calculations, I want to change size of `Group` control to calculated values inside this method, like so:

```
override public function updateDisplayList(containerWidth:Number, containerHeight:Number):void {
///// Here are some calculations.
layoutTarget.width = maxWidth;
layoutTarget.height = maxHeight + _padding;
}
```

But when I am doing so I got infinite loop here. `updateDisplayList` is called over and over again. And on each call `layoutTarget` has old width/height values.
Is there a right way to change `layoutTarget` size from `updateDisplayList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for layouts, you should change the target size in the measure method and set the measured.. values rather than width/height directly

```
override public function measure():void
{
    //calculate maxWidth and maxHeight here
    target.measuredWidth = target.measuredMinWidth = maxWidth;
    target.measuredHeight = target.measuredMinHeight = maxHeight+_padding;
}
```

measuredWidth/Height is the preferred component size and measuredMinWidth/Height is the minimum size for the component.